# ActiveMQ Artemis invisible consumer on $.artemis.internal.sf bridge queue

Tags: java, activemq-artemis

Sometimes the internal queue `$.artemis.internal.sf...` is building up messages. I can't reproduce the issue so I'm trying to gather as much infos as I can.

In the ActiveMQ Artemis web console when I click on the 1 consumer count in the queue page:
[image: ActiveMQ Artemis web console's queues listing]
the next page does not show any consumer on that queue:

[image: ActiveMQ Artemis web console's consumer listing, empty for $.artemis.internal.sf queue]

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

How can I check there is actually a consumer on the $.artemis.internal.sf queue and what consumer it is?

The logs shows the bridge is successfully connected:

```
2022-11-09 23:11:33,088 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221027: Bridge ClusterConnectionBridge@57073510 [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.my-cluster.aa352e1f-5708-11ed-a36c-00163ec45fe5, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.my-cluster.aa352e1f-5708-11ed-a36c-00163ec45fe5, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=masterA], temp=false]@580c8c14 targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl (identity=(Cluster-connection-bridge::ClusterConnectionBridge@57073510 [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.my-cluster.aa352e1f-5708-11ed-a36c-00163ec45fe5,queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.my-cluster.aa352e1f-5708-11ed-a36c-00163ec45fe5, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=masterA], temp=false]@580c8c14 targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=masterB, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61626&host=127-0-0-3], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]]::ClusterConnectionImpl@1876390738[nodeUUID=a8dd3f57-5708-11ed-aef9-a8a15976b7bf, connector=TransportConfiguration(name=masterA, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61616&host=127-0-0-1, address=, server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=masterA])) [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=masterB, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61626&host=127-0-0-3], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]] is connected
```

ActiveMQ Artemis version is 2.26.0 (same thing with 2.22.0).

I'm aware this queue is used to bridge between 2 live instances in a cluster and is managed by the `cluster-connection` config element in `broker.xml`.

I'm using a static cluster configuration (tcp based, no discovery-group, no broadcast-group).

masterA's nodeId: a8dd3f57-5708-11ed-aef9-a8a15976b7bf

masterB's nodeId: aa352e1f-5708-11ed-a36c-00163ec45fe5

I can add `broker.xml` of both masterA and masterB if relevent/required.

Any help will be much appreciated!

UPDATE: `cluster-connection` for masterA and masterB respectively are as follow:

cluster-connection for masterA

```xml
<cluster-connections>
    <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
        <connector-ref>masterA</connector-ref>
        <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
        <max-hops>2</max-hops>
        <static-connectors>
            <connector-ref>masterA</connector-ref>
            <connector-ref>slaveA</connector-ref>
            <connector-ref>masterB</connector-ref>
            <connector-ref>slaveB</connector-ref>
        </static-connectors>
    </cluster-connection>
</cluster-connections>
```

cluster-connection for masterB:

```xml
<cluster-connections>
    <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
        <connector-ref>masterB</connector-ref>
        <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
        <max-hops>2</max-hops>
        <static-connectors>
            <connector-ref>masterA</connector-ref>
            <connector-ref>slaveA</connector-ref>
            <connector-ref>masterB</connector-ref>
            <connector-ref>slaveB</connector-ref>
        </static-connectors>
    </cluster-connection>
</cluster-connections>
```

Comment: @JustinBertram the message count does not decrease at all, so I guess the bridge is stuck (no idea why atm). Messages arriving on queues that have consumers are consumed, but for messages coming on the other master not having consumer on the queue, these messages are stuck, as if they were no message redistribution (which works well if there is no building up in the bridge).We've been on that for... we've set up some alert and restart procedure to workaround that for now but not ideal since it disturbs our service.

Comment: no large message in our stuff. I guess 5k at the very most, and that's a rare case.

Comment: If we're going to talk about the bulding up, I should ask a different question and provide more details, the cluster-connection being a bit different

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74387642/artemis-artemis-internal-sf-sometimes-building-up-messages) is the question about the buildup with more details

Comment: I Just realized we do (our customers in fact) send large messages. I'll check if that matches with the times of the buildups and keep you posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The consumer on an internal store and forward cluster queue is the cluster bridge itself which is not a "normal" consumer. The bridge has no connection or session or anything like that. It's *directly* connected to the queue via an internal API. This is why it's not showing up in the web console.

Comment: Got it. Is it possible to add a cluster-connection parameter like the clientId? That would help identify the consumer IMO. Plus I might have missed that from the doc, but maybe emphasise what you just explained might be useful.